# What's the proper way to use the word "depth"? Is it "at 15 feet depth" or should it be "at a depth of 15 feet"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, measuring-units

For example:

**The phreatic surface is encountered at 15 feet depth.**

or

**The phreatic surface is encountered at a depth of 15 feet.**

The first sentence seems to be easier to read.

Comment: Typically "depth of 15 feet" or "15 feet deep"—"15 feet depth" is understandable, but not necessarily a typical phrasing.

Comment: @EmilyChapman That's because measuring units used attributively must be singular in English, which is why anything but a *fifteen-**foot** depth* in ungrammatical.

Comment: Or at fifteen feet of depth.